# How to create a wifi hotspot/share a connection on Kali linux?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I have two USB wireless cards, wlan0 and wlan1.

wlan0 is connected to a wifi far away using a yagi antenna (I have a house pretty far from "civilization" so I'm using an public open wifi)

So what i want, is to be able to share that connection to my android phone, since i can't really connected the yagi antenna to the android, i want to create a hotspot so that i can get internet to my android phone but still have the connection on my kali machine. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Why, o why do people have to use Kali Linux for tasks for which is wasn't made, and which will only cause you trouble? Please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), and use a distro more suitable for this. Any distro but Kali. And yes, making a hotspot is simple.

Answer (score 0):

First download some necessary drivers from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers). 
Then

In terminal type `lspci`
If you use usb wireless adapter type command `lsusb`

```
apt-get install hostapd dnsmasq
```

in terminal type:

```
sudo service hostapd stop
sudo service dnsmasq stop
sudo update-rc.d hostapd disable
sudo update-rc.d dnsmasq disable
```

set up config files
in terminal type:

`gedit /etc/dnsmasq.conf`
or `kate /etc/dnsmasq.conf` if you use kde...

add those lines to the config file:

```
# Bind to only one interface
bind-interfaces
# Choose interface for binding
interface=wlan0
# Specify range of IP addresses for DHCP leasses
dhcp-range=192.168.150.2,192.168.150.10
```

In terminal type:

```
gedit /etc/hostapd.conf
```

and add them

```
# Define interface
interface=wlan0
# Select driver
driver=nl80211
# Set access point name
ssid=myhotspot
# Set access point harware mode to 802.11g
hw_mode=g
# Set WIFI channel (can be easily changed)
channel=6
# Enable WPA2 only (1 for WPA, 2 for WPA2, 3 for WPA + WPA2)
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
```

You can change ssid name and password for anything you want here. Current config will create hotspot named myhotspot with password mypassword.

Now create anywhere you want a file named it `hotspot.sh` (best way to save script on Desktop)
Edit it with any text editor like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start
# Configure IP address for WLAN
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.150.1
# Start DHCP/DNS server
sudo service dnsmasq restart
# Enable routing
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# Enable NAT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
# Run access point daemon
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
# Stop
# Disable NAT
sudo iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
# Disable routing
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
# Disable DHCP/DNS server
sudo service dnsmasq stop
sudo service hostapd stop
```

You will probably need to change ppp0 in this to eth0 or any other number which refers to your wired connection.

Last step.

Now you can start your hotspot by starting script. Just run it... 
For me it looks like this:

```
root@kali:~# cd /root/Desktop/
root@kali:~/Desktop# ./hotspot.sh
```

If you doesn't want to do so, you can install `pwnstar` which works with any driver

Comment: I will try that! Btw, my first network adapter:
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n

The second one:

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0846:4260 NetGear, Inc. WG111v3 54 Mbps Wireless [realtek RTL8187B]

Comment: One more thing:
"You will probably need to change ppp0 in this to eth0 or any other number which refers to your wired connection."

Since i only have wireless connection should i choose wlan0?

Comment: try with ppp0 if it doesn't work then try wlan0

Comment: And in sudo ifconfig wlan0 , replace wlan0 with wlan1 if any error occurs(every wlan0 with wlan1)

Comment: Just tried it but got this:

root@Alpha:~/Desktop# ./hotspot.sh
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
root@Alpha:~/Desktop#

any idea?

Comment: I think that's not suitable for your network card, try pwnstar

Comment: It is only suitable for `ath5k` or `ath9k` drivers

Comment: Alright, i just installed pwnstar and launchet it. I'm not sure which option to choose,  the only one with internet access is a mitm one and i don't need that only internet access?

Comment: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?1406-PwnSTAR-running-on-Kali will guide you

Comment: Thank you. Well i guess It's outdated since this happens:
https://i.gyazo.com/e1cee5a8851b26d7e960f8313493a014.png

Will keep trying tho, thanks for your help and tips!